# Proving there are infinitely many integers having the identical set of prime factors.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, proof-writing, problem-solving

Let positive integers $a$ and $b$, and let $a_0, a_1, a_2 \ldots$ where $a_i = a + b*i$ is the infinite arithmetic sequence they determine. Prove that there are infinitely many  $a_i$ having the identical set of prime factors.

Comment: What are the $b_i$?  Do you intend for the formula to read $a_i = a + b \cdot i$?

Comment: This question is not very clear

Comment: It seems like an interesting question, and by the wording "the arithmetic sequence they determine" it seems clear OP means the sequence $a_i=a+bi$ as Sammy Black suggests in his comment. I think the question is, show there is an infinite subsequence for which all terms in it can be expressed as products involving the same fixed finite set $P$ of primes.

Comment: So, now we have complex prime numbers a+bi ;) .?

Comment: @SammyBlack You are right, a typo..

Answer (score 3):

Notice that it is enough to prove that the sequence $x_n=nb+1$ contains infintely many integers which have the same prime factors. In fact, if such a subsequence $x_{n_i}$ exists, the sequence $a+b(an_i)=ax_{n_i}$ is contained in the sequence $a_i$ and those numbers have the same set of prime factors.

Now observe that $x_n^2=n^2b^2+2nb+1=(n^2b+2n)b+1=x_{n^2b+2n}$, and obviously $x_n$ and $x_n^2$ have the same prime factors. Keep squaring to find the required sequence.